# How can I include a folder into the dist JAR as part of the build process using Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build.xml

I'm using Netbeans 6.9 , and I have looked into editing the build.xml file so that I can include directories and files in the jar file that results from building the project.

So my question is **How do I modify the build.xml file to put other folders in the jar?**

I have the following directory structure for my project

`ProjectDir/

/images/

/src/com/...

/lib/

and so on..`

And I want the jar file built by the ant build script to look like

`project.jar`
`/com`
`/lib` --this should include the jar files inside the lib folder
`/images` --this should include the jpg files
`/META-INF`

I need to do this because I "install" the jar file into Adobe Livecycle as a custom component and all of the lib jar files and images need to be included in the jar.

Also if there is a way to do this without using the build.xml file that would be fine also, currently I'm just copy the folders/files into the jar file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copydir.html

```
  <copydir src="${base.path}/lib/"
           dest="${build.path}/lib"
  />

  <copydir src="${base.path}/images/"
           dest="${build.path}/images"
  />

  <copydir src="${base.path}/src/com/"
           dest="${build.path}/com"
  />
  <copydir src="${base.path}/META-INF/"
           dest="${build.path}/META-INF"
  />
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

```
<jar destfile="project.jar"
     basedir="${build.path}"
     includes="**/*.*"
     />
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone see this, copydir is deprecated now, use:

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <copy todir="${dist.dir}/ace">
        <fileset dir="src/ace"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```