# How do I build a .jar in Netbeans with relative folder dependencies?

Tags: java, netbeans, build, compilation, io

I'm currently working on a simple RPG game with me and my friend in Java. One of the things I'm doing is drawing a tile-based map via .txt files, this way I can easily store and edit maps. Currently I'm loading maps like this:

[image]

And here is how the project is currently organized:

[image]

My question is, in Netbeans, how do I setup compiling so that when I do a clean compile, it automatically includes the .txt files in the right path so I can just send a .jar to a friend who wants to play? (Or send a .zip containing the .jar, and the /Maps/map1.txt files) Any solutions are helpful, thanks guys!

Comment: Two ways.  You can modify the `build.xml` on the `-post-jar` target or you could maintain the file as a bundled resource (within the jar)

Comment: jars are zips, btw.  Not much use in zipping a jar.

Comment: How does one perform the former? I've never fiddled with the build.xml and have no idea where to start with that.

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: I used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14879968/778118) to accomplish this task successfully last week.

Comment: @scottb zipping a jar is common practice - but not for compressing it - just to have one single file to transfer to the users containing the jar, some documentation and/or license files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MadProgrammer said, you can edit your `build.xml` on the `-post-jar` target. To do this, then you can refer to [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copydir.html) link, [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) link, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497019/how-can-i-include-a-folder-into-the-dist-jar-as-part-of-the-build-process-using) question.

1. If you have to include libraries as well, try a simple DOS script. Build the java project with Netbeans as usual, then create a directory named 'NewDist' inside NetBeans' project directory and create a file named JarMaker.bat. Here's the script.

   ```
   @echo off  
   echo * -------------------------------------------------------- *  
   echo * -      JarMaker V 2.0.0 - For Netbeans Projects        - *  
   echo * -------------------------------------------------------- *  
   echo 1) Creating Temporary Directory  
   mkdir classes  
   echo 2) Copying Library Jars  
   xcopy  /s /y ..\dist\lib\*.jar classes >> nul  
   cd classes  
   echo 3) Deflating Library Jars (this may take a while)  
   for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.jar') do jar xf %%a >> nul  
   del *.jar >> nul  
   cd ..  
   echo 4) Deflating Main Program Jar  
   xcopy /y ..\dist\*.jar classes >> nul  
   cd classes  
   for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.jar') do jar xf %%a >> nul  
   del *.jar >> nul  
   echo 5) Creating Unique Jar (this may take a while)  
   jar cvfm ../dist.jar META-INF/manifest.mf ./ >> nul  
   for /f %%a IN ('dir /b ..\..\dist\*.jar') do ren ..\dist.jar %%a >> nul  
   cd ..  
   echo 6) Removing Temporary Files  
   rmdir /s /q classes >> nul  
   echo * -------------------------------------------------------- *  
   echo * -         JarMaker V 2.0.0 - Process Complete          - *  
   echo * -------------------------------------------------------- *
   ```

[Source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419419/vc/netbeans-include-external-libraries-project)

Instead if you want to include images, [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273040/how-to-bundle-images-in-jar-file).

Comment: So I tried this:

http://i.imgur.com/jKc3jVu.png

and it still won't load the maps.

Comment: Try adding that right above the last line "</project>".
If it doesn't work for you, check my edited answer.